# Strange behavior of default constructor in a class inherited from POD struct

Tags: c++, default-constructor

This question relates to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555545/defining-copy-constructor-in-a-class-inherited-from-pod-struct).

As I mentioned in previous question I've decided to inherit my class from Win structure BITMAP to provide some extended functionality.

I've noticed interest detail in compiled program behavior. First I have defined default constructor for my class like below:

```
CPreviewFrame::CPreviewFrame():
   m_bufferSize( 0 )
{
   bmBits = NULL; //ensure that compiler in debug won't init it with 0xccccc... and delete[] will do the job
}
```

In idea compiler had to generate code which calls default constructor for base type even if it wasn't called manually in init list. But while debugging I noticed that BITMAP's data members are not initialized! I added manual initialize for BITMAP and it worked - all data members were initialized by zeros:

```
CPreviewFrame::CPreviewFrame():
   BITMAP( ),
   m_bufferSize( 0 )
{
   //bmBits = NULL; //it's not needed anymore probably
}
```

Why does it happen? Isn't compiler obligated to call default constructor or it's applied to classes only? (it can't be so I think - only difference is in default access qualifiers for members and for inheritance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not provide an explicit initializer for a POD-struct, then the object has an indeterminate initial value per Section 8.5/9 of the C++ standard.  Adding an initializer for `BITMAP` that is an empty set of parenthesis to the initializer list of your `CPreviewFrame` constructor value-initializes the `BITMAP` object per Section 8.5/7.  According to Section 8.5/5, that will mean all the non-static members of `BITMAP` will be zero-initialized since they are not arrays, unions, or class-types.

In your initial example though, you only initialized the `bmBits` member of the `BITMAP` structure in the actual body of the `CPreviewFrame` constructor ... that leaves the rest of the data-members of `BITMAP` with values that are indeterminate since no initializer was specified for the `BITMAP` structure itself.  Since each non-static data-member of a class is initialized before the actual body of the constructor is called, the lack of an explicit initializer for `BITMAP`, which is a non-static POD-struct data-member of your `CPreviewFrame` class, means that the behavior described in 8.5/9, where the values are set to an indeterminate initial value, takes effect.